# Deploying Python Flask app with MySQL database

Tags: python, flask

What hosting platform(s) can I use to host a Python (version 3.6) Flask app that uses a MySQL database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deploy Python with MySQL doesn't make sense. Did you mean how to connect your mysql to the flask app?

Answer (score 1):

As a good free option, you can host the Python flask portion on [Heroku](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploying-a-python-flask-app-to-heroku-41250bda27d0) and the MySQL database on [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/free-mysql-hosting)

Comment: But 000webhost don't allow to connect to external code